# Cloud Firestore & Cloud Firestore for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the difference between Cloud Firestore and Cloud Firestore for Firebase?

Here's a thread asking the same, but someone, please enlighten me.

https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/bb9n46/what_is_the_difference_between_the_cloud/

Is it the same? If not, which one to use?

Comment: Alex Mamo's answer looks really good to me. Would you care considering making it an accepted one? See his comment, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you have shared is talking about the differences between quickstarts, [Firestore as a service within GCP](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstarts) and [Firestore as a service within Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart). There also two different consoles for that. Both doing the same thing.

Please note that Cloud Firestore as a service is available with, or without Firebase SDKs.

> Is it the same?

The difference that I see between them is that in Firebase console you can set the security rules and you access other services like IAM, BigQuery, more easily.

> If not, which one to use?

If you are used to work in a Google Cloud Platform environment, use the Cloud console, otherwise use the Firebase console. So it depends on whatever your preference is.

For more informations, I recommend you read Doug Stevenson's post on medium.com regarding the same topic:

- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e